# How to Put Events to custom bus using aws php sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to send an event to custom event bus 'custom-event-bus'  using AWS PHP SDK using the following code

```
$client->putEvents([
    'Entries' => [ // REQUIRED
        [
            'Detail' => '{"alpha":"beta"}',
            'DetailType' => '',
            'EventBusName' => 'custom-event-bus',
            'Resources' => ['arn:aws:events:us-east-1:351123639451:event-bus/custom-event-bus',],
            'Source' => 'my-application',
            'Time' =>  time(),
        ],
     ],
]);
```

I am getting this error in the result:

```
AccessDeniedException (client): User: arn:aws:iam::351123639451:user/my-user is not authorized to perform: events:PutEvents on resource: arn:aws:events:us-east-1:351123639451:event-bus/default - {"__type":"AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::351123639451:user/my-user is not authorized to perform: events:PutEvents on resource: arn:aws:events:us-east-1:351123639451:event-bus/default"}
```

From this error message, it seems to be that it is sending an event on the default event bus, not the custom one to which I am sending.

Comment: Are you sure the error come from this exact call?

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEvents.html) here is correct, `EventBusName` is where you would specify the event bus name.

I would recommend checking that you have no other calls to this function name, perhaps taking it out and running independently.